# Does moving an app to Trash trigger its uninstaller?

Tags: macos, big-sur

Does cmd-backspacing an App (.app bundle somewhere in Applications folder) also tidy up system-wide configuration/data files etc. via some mechanism?

Comment: Can you define what makes an apps uninstaller? I don’t think there’s any technical implementation that forces that

Answer (score 3):

> Does moving an app to Trash trigger its uninstaller?

No!

Use an app like [**AppCleaner**](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to remove an unwanted *application* you've installed, and its associated *files/folders* its created.

Here is an example using **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**:

[image]

Had I just placed the **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app** in the **Trash** and emptied it, the other items listed would still remain.

<sup>Note: I'm not affiliated with the developer of the aforementioned *application*, just a satisfied user.</sup>

Comment: How are you so sure that it doesn't?

Comment: @theonlygusti, RE: "How are you so sure that it doesn't?" --  Because I've used a **Mac** for over 15 years and never has placing an _application_ into and emptying the **Trash** ever removed other than that was in the **Trash**!

Comment: @theonlygusti Because there's no mechanism in macOS that'd do that. (BTW, iOS is different -- there deleting an app *does* delete its data.)

Answer (score 1):

Some management utilities will attempt to clean up for you, but there are no system-level processes that will.

One such is Hazel (https://www.noodlesoft.com/).

[image]